# Creating miscroservice tar image for iOS EdgeEngine

Tags: edgeengine

I'm looking to deploy my microservice on my iOS app using the following func

```
public func deployMicroservice(edgeEngineAccessToken: String, config: MIMIKEdgeMobileClient.MIMIKMicroserviceDeploymentConfig, imageTarPath: String, completion: @escaping (MIMIKEdgeMobileClient.MIMIKMicroservice?) -> Void)
```

What steps should I take in creating this microservice tar image for **imageTarPath**?

Comment: do you already have an edge microservice that you would like to turn into a tar image or are you asking how to actually create the edge microservice?

Comment: @EarlGrey - Thanks for the quick reply, I was asking about turning an existing edge microservice into a tar image

Comment: no problem. the answer to your question is forthcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the existing microservices that you can deploy on iOS reside at the link below.

https://github.com/edgeMicroservice

Most of the microservices already come packaged as .tar files so all you need to do is deploy and start them.

For "starter-microservice" you build & package it via npm. How you build your own microservices is completely up to you